# How to prove that $x_1 + Y = x_2 + Y \Leftrightarrow x_1-x_2 \in Y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

$Y$ is defined by a subspace of a vector space $X$ over $F$.

Then, prove that, $\forall x_1, x_2\in X$, $$x_1 + Y = x_2 + Y \Leftrightarrow x_1-x_2 \in Y.$$

- Here, addition between a vector $x$ and a space $Y$ is defined by $\{x+y:y\in Y\}$.

---

Actually, I solved like the following:

1. Left way $(\Leftarrow)$

\begin{align}x_1+Y &= \{x_1+y: y\in Y\} \\&= \tag{a}\label{a}\{x_1 + (y_1 + y_2) : y_1\in Y, y_2=x_2-x_1\} \\&= \{x_2 + y_1 : y_1 \in Y \} \\&=x_2+Y\end{align}

2. Right way $(\Rightarrow)$
   \begin{align}
   FAILED
   \end{align}

I do not know how to start right way, and I am not sure that $\eqref{a}$ is reasonable. I would like to know the right way proof and whehter $a$ is reasnoble or not.

Comment: If $x_1-x_2\notinY$ then how can $(x_1-x_2)+Y=Y$?

Comment: (a) is okay only after you showed that $x_1-x_2\in Y$ so no

Comment: @Holo Actually, in the left way, $x_1 - x_2$ is asuumed in $Y$. You mean that if so, (a) is okay, isn't it? Thank you.

Comment: oh, I used to have the right first so I didn't payed attention, sorry. So you tell me does $y_1\in Y, y_2\in Y \implies y_1+y_2\in Y$? Think about the implications of this answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x_1+Y=x_2+Y$$ says that $$x_1+Y\subset x_2+Y$$ and
$$x_2+Y\subset x_1+Y.$$
I hope now it's clear.

For example, if $x_1+Y\subset x_2+Y$ then for all $ x_1+y_1$ there is $x_2+y_2$ for which $$x_1+y_1=x_2+y_2$$ or
$$x_1-x_2=y_2-y_1,$$ which says
$$x_1-x_2\in Y.$$

Comment: So how can I conclude that $x_1-x_2 \in Y$?

Comment: @Danny_Kim I added something. See now.

Comment: Thank you, I now understood it perfectly.

Comment: @Danny_Kim You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Direction 1 (Right way): You can rely on the definition provided and then the fact that $Y$ is closed under addition. 
\begin{align}
x_1 + Y & = x_2 + Y \\
x_1 + y_1  & = x_2 + y_2 \text{ for some } y_1,y_2 \in Y \\
x_1 - x_2  & = y_2 - y_1 \in Y
\end{align}

Direction 2 (Left way): I think what you have is legit, although it relies on line 2 on what Chinnapparaj R proves in his answer.

Comment: Thank you for very understandable answer.